# embed excel cell data in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

## what I want to do

I have an excel sheet that contains all the data, and I want to create a template in PowerPoint with place holders where if I update the Excel sheet it will be automatically reflected in the PowerPoint and then share that PowerPoint without the Excel file.

## what I have tried so far

I have tried copying the cells and paste special in PowerPoint.

## Problem

The problem of this method is that it will paste it as an image, and I still need the user to be able to edit the text INSIDE the PowerPoint itself.

Comment: To be clear, when you edit file Powerpoint1.ppt, say Excel2.ppt you want the Excel file outside of Powerpoint1.ppt to be updated?

Comment: no I just want to link the data from Excel to PowerPoint and be able to update the PowerPoint itself, doesn't matter if it is reflected in the Excel file

Comment: When you right-click the slide in PowerPoint to paste in the Excel data, are you choosing `Embed`? If you just paste, you should have an editable table...

Comment: Per my test, I suggest that you put the PowerPoint and Excel source files in the same folder for sharing.

Comment: @spikey_richie  i get what you are saying, but the excel file is updated daily, so i need the PowerPoint to be updated daily as well automatically before i share it if that makes anything, if i just paste it this won't happen and if i embedded it it will be a screenshot and non editable.

Comment: i think the only way is a macro i guess right?

Answer (score 1):

From the article
[Insert Excel data in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d):

> **Link a section of data in Excel to PowerPoint**
>
> 1. In Excel, open the saved workbook with the data you want to insert and link to.
> 2. Drag over the area of data you want to link to in PowerPoint, and on the Home tab, click or tap Copy.
> 3. In PowerPoint, click the slide where you want to paste the copied worksheet data.
> 4. On the Home tab, click the arrow below Paste, and select Paste Special.
>
>    [image]
> 5. In the Paste Special box, click Paste link, and then, under As, select Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object.
>
>    [image]

Comment: Thats what i did, but that way it only paste the object as a screenshot of the cell, can't be edited inside the PowerPoint itself which I need because i will share the PowerPoint without the excel file to external sources

Comment: I just tried it with a chart and it seems to work as a link, not an image. To assure yourself, right-click it in PowerPoint and select "Edit Data", then try to do the same in Excel. With me Excel refused, saying that the chart was already open in PowerPoint. Which Office version are you using?

Comment: yeah with charts it works just like i want but with normal text cells it doesn't work  for some reason, Microsoft disables the editing unless its a chart
Edit:
what i mean with text is that I am adding a text cell "A2" for example that contains  "AAA" to a text box area in PowerPoint

Comment: Text might be different.

Comment: yeah, thx for your time tho, really appreciate your help :D

Comment: @yousiffayed It may appear to be a screenshot but if you've followed harrymc's instructions exactly, it's a linked Excel object. It will update itself when you change the Excel data, save the file then open the PPT file again or if you force an update using the links dialog. You can also rightclick it and choose (from memory here) Excel Object > Open or Excel Object > Edit to either edit the linked data in place or open it in Excel for editing.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I get what you are saying, but I need to update the text inside PowerPoint without the excel file being present since I will be emailing the PowerPoint without the excel file, which can't really be done, thx for your time tho, really appreciate it

Comment: Without the Excel file, linking isn't the appropriate solution.

Comment: @yousiffayed as harrymc has mentioned, if you can't keep the PPT and the linked Excel file together, then the link will break and the recipient won't be able to edit the file. You'll need to embed instead, but if you do that, edits to the external XL file will no longer cause updates in the PPT file.